# Regular expression to match 3 or more plus signs

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want a regular expression in VB.Net that matches any occurrence of three or more plus signs (+++) in any string like:

```
Hello John +++++ I liked your post +++ it is great ++++++++ thank you
```

I tried this expression, but it is not working:

```
\bC\+\+\+\S*
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please show the code you have tried and explain in detail why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
(\+\+\+)\S*
```

Thank you ++++++++++++++